# generate swagger spec from servicestack api

Tags: servicestack, swagger, soapui

I am using servicestack as REST framework. 
The swagger UI plugin is very help full for manual testing and debugging.

Now I want to do more automatic testing, performance testing, with a tool like SoapUI.

My question is, is there a way to generate the swagger spec from within service stack? So i can import it into SoapUI.

I don't want to create all the requests in SoapUI manually.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Open API v2.0 Specification

ServiceStack implements the [OpenAPI v2.0 Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) in its [Open API Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) which you can install from NuGet with:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi
```

Then register in your AppHost with:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature());
```

When enabled you can access the Open API spec for your services at the `/openapi` endpoint. This is what the `/swagger-ui/` uses to generate its dynamic UI for your Services.

#### Generating REST Client using Open API Spec

Which you can also use with [Azure's AutoRest client](https://guthub.com/Azure/Autorest) to [generate an AutoRest client from the spec](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#generating-autorest-client).

But I don't see what the Swagger/OpenAPI Spec has to do with SoapUI? Soap Web Services are described and can have their clients generated from a [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl), not the Open API spec.

#### SOAP Support

[ServiceStack's SOAP Support](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support) also generates the WSDL for your Services which you can find linked on your [Metadata Page](http://docs.servicestack.net/metadata-page).

#### Older Swagger 1.2 Spec

Alternatively ServiceStack also supports the older Swagger 1.2 Spec with its [Swagger Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api) which you can install from NuGet with:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Api.Swagger
```

Then register in your AppHost with:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
```